# How to determine if name and lname is not in file

Tags: c++

The program, is basically sussposed to iterate a file containing the elements

```
Harry Keeling (202)806-4830
Frank James (301)123-3459
Arthur Paul (202)865-9090
Todd Shurn (410)560-8909
Richard Okpala 202 388 410
```

what my current program is outputting the phonenumber if  firstname and lastname is present in file but if its nothow do i output phone number isnt here my current code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void lookup_name(ifstream&, string&, string&, string&);  // prototype
int main()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    string name, lastname, phonenumber;

    char choice;


    do
    {
        myfile.open("infile.txt");
        cout << "What is the First name? " << endl;
        cin >> name;
        cout << "what is your last name?" << endl;

        cin >> lastname;
        lookup_name(myfile, name, lastname, phonenumber);

        cout << "Do you want to lookup another name<Y/N" << endl;
        cin >> choice;


    } while (choice == 'Y');
    return 0;
}
void lookup_name(ifstream& myfile, string& name, string& lastname, string& phonenumber)
{
    string name1, name2, fullname, secondname, dummy;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        myfile >> name1 >> name2;
        fullname = name1 + name2;
        secondname = name + lastname;
        if (fullname == secondname) {
            myfile >> phonenumber;
            cout << phonenumber << endl;
            myfile.close();
            break;
        }
        else if (fullname != secondname) {
            myfile >> dummy;
            phonenumber = dummy;
        }
```

Comment: Suggestion: Load the file into a std::vector of structures, then search the vector.

Comment: ? have not learning about vectors im reading data from a file.

Comment: Good time to learn.

Comment: Instead of using ``break``, use ``return``.  Then, anything appearing after & outside the loop will be executed only if the number was not found.

Comment: put the return were?

Comment: This code appears to be a derivative of  [code I posted earlier this morning](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42984948/65863) in reply to another question. Is there a reason why you rewrote it? Did the earlier code not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Just return whether you found it or not from your lookup function

```
int lookup_name(ifstream& myfile, string& name, string& lastname, string& phonenumber)
{
    string name1, name2, fullname, secondname, dummy;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        myfile >> name1 >> name2;
        fullname = name1 + name2;
        secondname = name + lastname;
        if (fullname == secondname) {
            myfile >> phonenumber;
            cout << phonenumber << endl;
            myfile.close();
            return 1;
        }
        else if (fullname != secondname) {
            myfile >> dummy;
            phonenumber = dummy;
        }
   }
 return 0;
}
```

Then use the return value

```
if ( ! lookup_name(myfile, name, lastname, phonenumber) ) {
   cout << "Nope, didn't find it!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: do i put the if statement in main im confused?

Comment: it has to be a void function not a vale returning

Comment: yes, replace the original lookup_name line, with these 3 lines.

Comment: it has to be a void function how will it work with a void function?

Comment: just replace `return 0;` with `cout << "Nope, didn't find it!" << endl;`